# Double array passed by C# to C++ dll does not modify correctly from the dll

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, vector, dll

I am trying to pass an array of doubles and process them from a C++ DLL. The array does indeed get passed correctly, as can be verified. But, if I try to change the values in the C++ DLL, the array (when I check in the C# calling code) gets shrunk to an array with just one value - the original first value and not the values modified in the C++ DLL. I am unable to figure out where the vector gets resized.

The C++ DLL code:

```
.cpp:
     
FASTFULLBANDSOLVER_API double fn(vector<double>& p, int pLength)
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < pLength; ++i)
    {
        sum += p[i];
        p[i] = (double)i;
    }

    return sum;
}

.h:
extern "C" FASTFULLBANDSOLVER_API double fn(std::vector<double>& p, int pLength);
```

The C# calling code:

```
[DllImport("FastFullBandSolver.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern double fn(ref double[] p, int pLength);

public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            double[] _p = new double[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
            int pl = 5;
            double sum = fn(ref _p, pl);
            MessageBox.Show(sum.ToString());
        }
```

The sum returned is 100, which is correct. However, _p gets changed to just one element array containing value 10 in it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: C++ `vector<double>` is not the same structure as `double[]` of C#. This shouldn't work by any means.

Comment: You can't "pass around" C++ objects. Their "internal structure" isn't explicitly defined anywhere, so it can't be marshalled

Comment: Oh okay. Got it. Thanks